# bootstrap thumbnail buttons not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap thumbnails [on my page from here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

All this thumbnail have varying content in paragraph i.e in "`<p>...</p>`". This give rise to problem of aligning the below buttons. Some buttons moving up and some down. I tried with "`<br/>`" tags but they don't work and showing different results on different browser.

**Note : There are total 8 thumbnails. 4 in upper row and 4  row it.**

Comment: Don't understand what exactly you wont? Plz add more clarification..

Comment: @MinalChauhan What you didn't understood?

Comment: your content is not fixed, so that your button are not properly align in some position in column right?

Comment: @MinalChauhan Yes. I need all buttons to look on same line.

Comment: So you need to add fixed height to the first p tag...

Comment: yes, add min-height to first p tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using a min-height to the p tag and the min height should be more than the height of the maximum caption content ---

**working example**

```css
.p_info {
  min-height: 330px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p class="p_info">...Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit....Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit
        non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit....Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula
        ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define the height to the `<p>`first child and set property `overflow:scroll`.

here is the example [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/swasatz/dnoffrhy/)

Answer (score 0):

simply put the `width` of `p` tag

```
<p style="width:some width">...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `min-height` and `max-height` on your image and paragraph tag, so they all take similar spaces, then all your `button` will be align perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this inline style to the buttons

```
style='vertical-align: bottom;'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
```

to align buttons to specific positions
i suggest you to put buttons in different row

Comment: Sorry I forgot mention that there are total 8 thumbnail. 4 in one row and 4 below of it.

Comment: for my case code you given is working properly .. what is your exact problem.. would u like to share some snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
.caption p { 
    height: 42px; /*set the height*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```